# Loading HTML inside div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am making a slideshow system that would show previous & next buttons for the obvious jobs. The slides however will be seperate html files, like slide1.html, slide2.html. Thickbox and other plugins load html asynchronously within them. What is the best method to do this. I am writing a jQuery plugin for the whole process.

I would love ideas from JavaScript experienced people.

Thanks a lot in advance. Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're asking. It's dead easy to load HTML snippets into a div using [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$("selector_for_the_div").load("your_url");
```

Example [(live copy)](http://jsbin.com/awisa4/3):

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var currentSlide = 0;
  var slides = [
    "http://jsbin.com/enuju4/",
    "http://jsbin.com/enuju4/2",
    "http://jsbin.com/enuju4/3"
    ];

  loadSlide(0);

  $("#btnNext").click(function() {
    loadSlide(currentSlide + 1);
  });

  $("#btnPrev").click(function() {
    loadSlide(currentSlide - 1);
  });

  function loadSlide(index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < slides.length) {
      currentSlide = index;
      $('#slideHolder').load(slides[currentSlide]);
    }
  }

});
```

You could cache the slides, or just rely on the browser's caching. Button enabling/disabling and such would obviously be nice...

Comment: that works...but will the load function replace the existing slide with the new one? is there a empty function I could use before load?

Comment: @Aayush: Yes, `load` *replaces* the content of the target element. No need to empty it first. (This is demonstrated by the linked example.)